# Constructing a Vierbein for the Robertson-Walker Metric

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I assume that this is standard but I cannot find it written down anywhere.  I wish to construct a vierbein for the Robertson-Walker metric in relativistic cosmology:

$ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2 \bigg( \frac{dr^2}{1 - kr^2} + r^2 (d \theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2) \bigg)$

This can be done in matrix terms by solving

$g = e^T \eta e$,

where the vierbein $e$ is a quadratic matrix and $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric.  However, when I try to solve I cannot get the minus signs to work as some of the components of $g$ end up with the wrong sign?

Edit: I think I made a sign mistake when writing out the matrix for $g$, if this is corrected then one can write out a vierbein immediately.

Comment: It suffices to find $1$-forms $\omega^0,\omega^1,\omega^2,\omega^3$ such that $$ds^2 = (\omega^0)^2-(\omega^1)^2-(\omega^2)^2-(\omega^3)^2.$$ You can find an example directly from the formula for the metric.

Comment: @Deane On Wikipedia, it states that $\eta$ is the Lorentz metric, I am bit confused what they mean, this is the Minkowski metric isn't it?  So spacetime index like $\mu$ is raised/lowered with $g$ and local Lorentz index like $a$ is raised/lowered with $\eta$?

Comment: I see. You do have the wrong signs in your formula for $ds^2$.